# Evaluating contour integral without using Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Find the value of the integration without using Cauchy integral
>   formula/Residue theorem:
>
> $\int_{C}\cfrac{dz}{z^2+1}$ where C is a simple closed contour
>   oriented in counter clockwise direction containing z = i as an
>   interior point and also C lies in the interior of the circle $|z-i| =
>  \cfrac{1}{2}$.

Now, I tried to solve it in this way:

$\int_{C}\cfrac{dz}{z^2+1}$ = $\int_{C}\cfrac{dz}{(z+i)(z-i)}$ = $\cfrac{i}{2}(\int_{C}\cfrac{dz}{z+i} - \int_{C}\cfrac{dz}{z-i})$

I was thinking of using the fact that both the integrals inside the brackets would be equal to $\pi i$, but I am not sure about that.

Can someone please give me a hint for solving this question?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know about winding numbers? That's one possibility that might be what the question is looking for. Otherwise, you can choose any contour you like, so choose one for which the integral is easy to compute. You also have Cauchy's theorem to remove the integral of the analytic part of the partial fractions.

Comment: @Chappers : Sorry, I have no idea about winding numbers. As for choosing any contour, should I use the fact that z = i lies within C? Also, by Cauchy's theorem, I can directly write that integral would be zero (right?) since it is given that C is simply closed.

Comment: If one may not use Cauchy's Integral Formula or the Residue Theorem, then may one use Cauchy's Integral Theorem?

Comment: @Dr.MV, I am not sure actually. But, since, it is not mentioned specifically, let us assume that anything goes...

Comment: @Vishwesh Thanks.  I took the liberty to assume that inasmuch as it was not stated as forbidden, then one may proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to evaluating the integral with appealing to either Cauchy's Integral Formula or the Residue Theorem relies on Cauchy's Theorem.

If $f(z)$ analytic within a open region (simply connected) in the complex plane, then for any contour (with finite length) $C$ contained in that open region,

$$\oint_C f(z) dz=0$$

Now, in the problem at hand, $f(z)$ is not analytic in the region encircled by $C$.  However, we may evaluate the integral on a "deformed" contour $C'$ that does not enclose any singularity.  Then,

$$\oint_{C'} f(z)dz=0$$

If we deform $C$ by adding a "key-hole" contour that "cuts out" the singularity with a small circle $\gamma$ of radius $\epsilon$, centered at the singular point then

$$\oint_{C'} f(z)dz=\oint_C f(z)dz-\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$$

where the opposing contributions from the "key length" integrations annihilate one another.

Thus, this reduced the problem to evaluating the integral over $\gamma$.  For this problem,

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma}f(z) dz&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi}{(i+\epsilon e^{i\phi})^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi}{2i\epsilon e^{i\phi}+\epsilon^2 e^{i2\phi}}\right)\\\\
&=\pi
\end{align}$$

Comment: Okay, I think I got this. Here the singular point is z = i. So, in case of any similar problem, if there is no singular point, I can directly use any integration method which best suits the situation and if there **is** a singular point, then I can use Cauchy theorem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that both integrals will be $\pi i$. The circle of integration encloses $i$, but it doesn't enclose $-i$. So $\frac{1}{z + i}$ is analytic within an open domain containing $C$.

Comment: But, how can I use the fact that $\cfrac{1}{z+i}$ is analytic? I think that I am missing something important. Also, would the other integral be $\pi i$ or $2\pi i$ ?

Comment: If a function is analytic, any integral over a curve it determined by its endpoints. This is a closed curve, so the endpoints are the same. That is, the integral over a closed curve of an analytic function is zero.

Comment: Superb! So, you used Cauchy's theorem there?

Comment: Yes, that's Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now. But, one thing that I can't get is what should be the final value of the integral ? Shouldn't it be zero ?

Comment: No, it won't be zero. Exactly one of the two integrals in the final pair of parentheses is zero, while the other is not (and should be evaluated by Cauchy's Residue Theorem).